# Enabling APC in shell?

Tags: php, shell, apc

I have APC installed and enabled, working flawlessly on my site in apache2/php5.

However, it doesn't work in shell directly.

I've created a test.php:

```
<?php

apc_store('test', 'apc works!');
echo apc_fetch('test');
echo "\n";
echo 'Script works!';
echo "\n";

?>
```

This is the output:

```
rimmer:/home# /usr/bin/php5 -f test.php 

Script works!
```

To provide more info:

```
rimmer:/home# cat /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/apc.ini
extension=apc.so
apc.enabled=1
apc.cache_by_default=1
apc.max_file_size=32M
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

EDIT

```
rimmer:~# php --ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc/php5/cli
Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /etc/php5/cli/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/apc.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/curl.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/gd.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/imagick.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/imap.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/mcrypt.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/mysql.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/mysqli.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/pdo.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/pdo_mysql.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/pdo_pgsql.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/pgsql.ini
```

Comment: Just in case check the output of `php --ini`

Comment: You need apc.enable_cli = 1 in your CLI ini.

Comment: Is apc supposed to be shared between CLI and live apache2?

Comment: No, those are two separate processes. You can only share shared memory, not private memory between two different processes.